# How to change ? in URL to /

Tags: php, yii2

I am using the following code

```
$user_id         =   Yii::$app->user->id;`
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl.$lang_trans_id.'/'.$seflinks['0']->cms_page_alias.'?'.$user_id; ?>">
```

So the url looks like:

[http://localhost/xxx/en/profile?66](http://localhost/xxx/profile?66)

Is there anyway i can make the URL look like

http://localhost/xxx/en/profile/66

Answer (score 1):

Simple replace `?` with `/`.

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl.$lang_trans_id.'/'.$seflinks['0']->cms_page_alias.'/'.$user_id; ?>">
```

Comment: It will show 'Page not found' error because it changes the page

Comment: `66` is should be work as a param for `profile` function. Check with placing die is it executing or not.